# PySpark DataFrame not parsing time correctly

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with datetime as string type as such:

```
Row(Created Date=u'7/6/15 10:58', Closed Date=u'7/22/15 1:07)
```

I want to convert it to a datetime so I try this way. First I remove all rows with None.

```
df = df.na.drop(subset=["Created Date"])
df = df.na.drop(subset=["Closed Date"])
```

Then I specify the format of the datetime string

```
func =  F.udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), DateType())
```

Then I apply the functions to these two columns as such

```
df = df.withColumn('Created Date', func(F.col('Created Date')))
df = df.withColumn('Closed Date', func(F.col('Closed Date')))
```

However when I take a look at my DataFrame the datetime is in this format

```
Row(Created Date=datetime.date(2015, 7, 6), Closed Date=datetime.date(2015, 7, 22)
```

It seems the hours and seconds have mysteriously disappeared. Am I parsing the datetime incorrectly or is something else the culprit? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

- You're using `DateType` when you need `TimestampType` (this is why you get unexpected result):

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

  df = sc.parallelize([
      (u'7/6/15 10:58', '7/22/15 1:07')
  ]).toDF(['Created Date', 'Closed Date'])

  as_timestamp = F.udf(
      lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), TimestampType()
  )

  df.select(
      as_timestamp("Created Date"), as_timestamp("Closed Date")
  ).show(1, False)
  ```

  ```
  +----------------------+---------------------+
  |<lambda>(Created Date)|<lambda>(Closed Date)|
  +----------------------+---------------------+
  |2015-07-06 10:58:00.0 |2015-07-22 01:07:00.0|
  +----------------------+---------------------+
  ```
- You're using UDF where you can use native functions (this introduces a significant performance penalty):

  ```
  def native_as_timestamp(colname, format='MM/dd/yy HH:mm'):
      """
      https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
      """
      return F.unix_timestamp(
          colname, format
      ).cast(TimestampType()).alias(colname)

  df.select(
      native_as_timestamp('Created Date'), native_as_timestamp('Closed Date')
  ).show(1, False)
  ```

  ```
  +---------------------+---------------------+
  |Created Date         |Closed Date          |
  +---------------------+---------------------+
  |2015-07-06 10:58:00.0|2015-07-22 01:07:00.0|
  +---------------------+---------------------+
  ```

  In the latest versions (>= 2.2.0) you can replace `unix_timestamp(...).cast(...)` with [`to_timesatmap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=to_timestamp#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp):

  ```
  df.select(
      F.to_timestamp('Created Date', 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm').alias('Created Date'),     
      F.to_timestamp('Closed Date', 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm').alias('Closed Date')
  ).show(1, False)
  ```

Comment: using spark-scala, the cast can be done directly.. right?

Comment: @stack0114106 Not with non-standard (not ISO 8601)  format though in the latest versions you could simplify this to `to_timestamp`.